# rails 5 request not sending german letters to controller

Tags: encoding, ruby-on-rails-5

Using "`ISO-8859-1`" encoding.

layout/application.html.erb

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

application.rb

```
    config.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
```

database.yml

```
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: latin1
  collation: latin1_swedish_ci
  charset: latin1
```

Above is my declarations in Rails.

So now i can see proper data on html.erb page in **german** format. eg. WÄRTSILÄ

But while sending request from page to controller **params**  are omitting special chars like **Ä**. Getting following string in controller.

```
"name"=>"WRTSIL"
```

Getting following error for simple_format()

`ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8)`

Does above declarations are right for German letters?

**or What encoding should be used on page level to accept German letters and to save it in database what should be updated in database.yml**

or there is something i need to update for application server(puma / thin)

Versions:

```
`Rails 5` 
`Ruby-2.5.1`
```